# Как загрузить фото в ImageView из интерета

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Как загружать фотографии по прямой ссылке из интернета? У меня есть фотография — https://pp.vk.me/c320525/v320525404/5502/wDguXeHdmZk.jpg

Мне нужно загрузить ее в `ImageView`. Я нашел такой способ:

```
                        URL url = new URL("https://pp.vk.me/c320525/v320525404/5502/wDguXeHdmZk.jpg");
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        userPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Однако он возвращает ошибку. При чем просто "null"...

---

Так как же все-таки загрузить фотографию?

Comment: А как насчет воспользоваться поиском? Таких вопросов штук 10 уже тут

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте одну из множества библиотек для скачивания, отображения и кэширования картинок и сети. Например [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

А ошибка у вас может быть из-за запроса в сеть из UI потока. Но без логов ошибки этого точно не узнать, увы.

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы правы. Я запрашивал изображение из UI потока. Жаль, что придется подключать библиотеку из-за одной картинки :)).

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, если она одна, то можете просто в другой поток вынести скачивание. Но вам ещё придётся обработать вариант без инета... А вот либа сама закэширует и даже без интера сразу покажет уже однажды загруженную картинку.